# How to make MSVC complain about multi-word functional cast?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using functional-style casts for primitive types:
`auto b = int(a);`

however, according to the standard, multi-word functional-style casts such as
`auto c = unsigned int(b);` are not allowed.

MSVC allows multi-word functional-style casts, while other compilers do not.
How can I make MSVC to be standard-compliant here?

https://godbolt.org/z/xvfPzbG9h

Comment: Getting MSVC to do anything standard-compliant is an uphill battle.

Comment: AFAIK there is no "pedantic" equivalent option in MSVC.

Comment: @paddy that was a thing of the past. MSVC was the **first** to support C++14/C++17/C++20 and they've been spending effort standardizing everything for years. Many things GCC and Clang still didn't support as of now or until years later

Comment: The /permissive- option was meant to diagnose non-compliant constructs from legacy codebases.  Use Help > Send Feedback to remind them to implement it for functional-style cast expressions.